# OnRowRender Corona SDK 1076 not show data

Tags: list, widget, coronasdk

Good afternoon,

I have a problem when displaying the contents of my table in a list. The action does not make the impression of the data in each row and do not understand why.

I have the 1076 version of Corona SDK and does not work, but with the previous IF it worked.

I hope your help.

```
  local function onRowRender( event )
    print("oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo")
      local phase = event.phase
      local row = event.row
      local rowGroup = event.view
      local label = aux.corrigeEspeciales (rowTitles[ row.index ])
      local color = 20 
      print ("label" .. label)
      row.itemName = label
      row.textObj = display.newRetinaText(rowGroup,label, 0, 0, "Verdana", 12 )
      row.textObj:setTextColor( color )
      row.textObj:setReferencePoint( display.CenterLeftReferencePoint )
      row.textObj.x, row.textObj.y = 20, rowGroup.contentHeight * 0.5
      rowGroup:insert( row.textObj )
      row.arrow = display.newImage( "images/tiendarowArrow.png", false )
      row.arrow.x = rowGroup.contentWidth - row.arrow.contentWidth * 2
      row.arrow.y = rowGroup.contentHeight * 0.5
      rowGroup:insert( row.arrow )             
  end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can show text info in 2013.1076 Corona SDK version using:

```
      local phase = event.phase
      local row = event.row
      local rowGroup = event.view
      local label = aux.corrigeEspeciales (rowTitles[ row.index ])
      local color = 20 
      row.itemName = label

      local rowTitle = display.newText(row,label, 0, 0, "Verdana", 12 )
      rowTitle.x = row.x - ( row.contentWidth * 0.5 ) + ( rowTitle.contentWidth * 0.5 )
      rowTitle.y = row.contentHeight * 0.5
      rowTitle:setTextColor( 0, 0, 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Corona 1076 I think uses Widget 2.0 widgets.  They require a different syntax for determining the row group.  See this article on updating your widgets to the new syntax.

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/migration.html

Also there is a new public build, 1135 that contains considerable bug fixes to the widget library.  I would suggest upgrading so that you have these fixes.